# A use for boost::any?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, boost

I'm not sure if this calls for `boost::any`. I'd rather use native templates if there's a pattern that does what I want. I have this class (which I've written here using `boost::any`) defined in a header:

```
template <typename T> class Observable;

class Report
{
    typedef unordered_map<wstring, std::shared_ptr<Observable<boost::any>>> ObservationMap;

public:
    void AddObservable(const wstring& name, std::shared_ptr<Observable<boost::any>> observable);
    const Observable<boost::any>& GetObservable(const wstring& name) const;

protected:
    ObservationMap observations;
};
```

and `Observable` is defined like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Observable
{
    typedef T Type;

    T Quantity;
    // ...
};
```

I would really like some way of adding `Observable`s of any quantity type to `Report`s. Is there a more effective way of doing this without incurring the overhead of `boost::any`?

**Edit:** An example of code that adds observables to the report class would be something like this:

```
Observable<float> obs1;
obs1.Quantity = 1.1f;
Observable<int> obs2;
obs2.Quantity = 5;

Report report;
report.AddObservable("Height", obs1);
report.AddObservable("Age", obs2);
```

Then somewhere else I would want to read those quantities. Say I receive the report:

```
void DoSomethingWithReport(Report& report)
{
    float height = report.GetObservable("Height").Quantity;
    int age = report.GetObservable("Age").Quantity;
}
```

Something like that. Of course, I'd really add other methods to check if those observations are present in the report, etc. I prefer it to be generic because I don't know beforehand, at the receiving site, what it will contain, so I'd like some flexibility.

Comment: The design to observe something unspecified looks wrong to me

Comment: Well, these are going to be floats, ints, and so on. Maybe some 2D and 3D vectors as well.

Comment: Derive all Observeables from a common `BaseObservable` which offers virtual functions for everything your Report must do to it. Still, you might be going dangerously generic there.

Comment: Thanks. I am considering that. One problem I find is that if I return `BaseObservable` from `GetObservable()` I'd have to cast it to its proper type before I can access its value, which may incur overhead anyway.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato: you return a reference. and you shouldn't need a cast. if you need, that's almost definitely another design flaw. how about virtual getValue() in base class?...... anyway, this whole conversation seems ridiculously generic. if you have problems grasping OO concepts, perhaps you should come up with something concrete.

Comment: @Deduplicator in the Report class. 
@KarolyHorvath, I'm trying to understand how you mean exactly. I have to have something like `T& GetValue()` in `BaseObservable`, which means it has to be a template class or function anyway, no?

Comment: It should be a template method, yes. `template<class T> const Observable<T>& GetObservable(const wstring& name) const`

Comment: Thanks, Deduplicator.

Comment: yes.... and no (`BaseValue&` ?)... show a concrete example. I have no idea what you want to do with a generic `T&`... both approaches have its merits. but blindly choosing one of them without knowing the requirements would be foolish!

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question. Have a look at the bottom. These are mainly native types.

Comment: well, your example clearly relies on *knowing* what you observe (you know there's a `float` `"Height"`). seems very contrived to me. you lose all the flexibility that this approach could give you. why don't you simply put a `float height` member in `report`?

Comment: I also said why at the end of the edit. I don't know what it will contain. I will look for certain things that might or might not be there. Since there's a whole lot of possibilities, I don't want to put in a bunch of fields that are not going to be filled with useful data.

Comment: @Karoly: Not neccessarily. Depends on having the right interface from `BaseObservable`. Those who change the data will need to know the type, those who only observe might only have to know that the value was updated and should be re-displayed or some such.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato: I hope you are aware that you'll lose the chance to do static type checking (ouch!)... e.g.: what's the type of the value for `"Height"`? the compiler certainly won't know...

Comment: I know there are drawbacks. That's why I'm asking, to get a feel of what you folks think. I'd like flexibility of course, but not at the price of everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::any` is a decently efficient way to store a value of a type you have prevented the compiler (for whatever reason or design requirement) from knowing.

If there are only a limited set of operations you want to perform on the data, you can use type erasure instead and/or a base interface class. But that requires knowing all uses for the data when you define the interface.

If you have a limited set of data types, `boost::variant` or the like can be more efficient than `any`.  You can even have a `variant` that includes `any` or a type erasure object (or objects) in the set of types.

You can use reflection or similar techniques to store complex data and wrap it in `any` accessors (or `variant`) if your data is sometimes structured, which can reduce storage overhead somewhat.  Basically structured data becomes a type erased type with member access by name.

Much of these techniques end up mirroring type behaviour of scripting or bytecode languages: sometimes it might be a good idea to write the part of your app that needs this amount of compile time flexibilty in a mainly runtime type checked language.

Finally you may decide you do not need all this needless runtime dynamic typing.